# Rasberry Pi Mouse Click Action

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, python

I am making a photo taking app however, I am having a problem getting it to react when doing a mouse click. What is the specific code needed to change it to take a picture when a mouse button is clicked? Here is the code.

```
from gpiozero import *
from picamera import *
from time import *
from guizero import *

#Takes 3 pictures
def take_picture():
        global output
        for i in range(3):
                #Timer
                message.set("\n 3")
                message.color("black")
                message.font_size(100)
                sleep(1)
                message.clear()
                message.set("\n 2")
        message.color("black")
                message.font_size(100)
                sleep(1)
                message.clear()
                message.set("\n 1")
        message.color("black")
                message.font_size(100)
                sleep(1)
                message.clear()
                message.set("SMILE!")
                message.color("red")
                message.font_size(150)
                sleep(1)
                message.clear()
                message.set("Saving image..")
                message.color("black")
                message.font_size(50)
                #image File Name
                output = strftime("/home/pi/mypibooth/photos/image-%d-%m_%H:%M:%S.png", gmtime())
                camera.capture(output, use_video_port=True)
                message.clear()
                message.set("Push the button to take three photos")
                message.color("black")
                message.font_size(50)

#GPIO button asignment
take_pic_btn = Button(25)
take_pic_btn.when_pressed = take_picture

#Camera settings
camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (2556, 1600)
#camera.resolution = (2556, 1440)
#camera.resolution = (1920, 1080)
camera.hflip = True
camera.vflip = True

output = ""

#GUI
app = App("My Pi Booth")
app.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
camera.start_preview(alpha=200)
message = Text(app, "Push the button to take three photos", size=36, color="black", font="Helvetica", grid=None, align=None)
#onscreen button to test if you don't have a physical GPIO button plugged inn:
#new_pic = PushButton(app, take_picture, text="text on button")
app.display()
```

Comment: your code appears to be improperly indented

Answer (score 1):

Can you show us an example of the output when running?  Are there any errors?  Please try to provide as many details as possible when asking questions to help us to help you.

In order for your program to see a "click", it will probably need to be open, and in focus.  I see you're trying to create a fullscreen window.  Does that window show up?  Are you clicking on that window and nothing happens?

Why is this line commented out:

```
#new_pic = PushButton(app, take_picture, text="text on button")
```

I don't have familiarity with the library, but it looks to me like this is what controls what happens when a button is pushed, and it is [commented out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comment_(computer_programming)).

Have you tried running the program by removing the `#` from the `PushButton` line?

This is Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange, so be sure to check out other places, such as [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) when your question is more closely related to programming than Raspberry Pis.